# Calling method of Entity Class - CoreData: Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I may be going about this the wrong way, I'm attempting to call a method of an entity subclass.

```
func addPlayer(_name: String, _team: String, _position: String, _stats: NSDictionary){

    let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Player", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let player = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    player.setValue(_name, forKey: "name")
    player.setValue(_position, forKey: "position")
    player.setValue(_team, forKey: "teamAbbr")

    player.setValue(player.calculateTradeValue() as! Player, forKey: "tradeValue")
```

The last line gives me an error 
`Value of type NSManagedObject has no member calculateTradeValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have a few questions.
1) Are you using CoreData with your project? That's what I'm guessing due to your use of managedObjectContext, in which I assume you've created an entity called Player in your data model?

2) It'll be easier for you and others to read your code if you're as consistent as possible with your naming conventions. I'd suggest naming your "managedContext" -> "managedObjectContext". It may seem insignificant, but its a good practice to get into.

3) I'd suggest declaring your managedObjectContext outside of your function; right now the only place in your code that has access to whats saved in the managedObjectContext is within this function. If you declare it at the top of your class, outside of any functions, you'll have access to it throughout the entire class.

4) I'm not sure how to tell you how to fix your actual issue, but take a look at how I put together my code to insert a new instance of an object into the managedObjectContext. In CoreData, I have an entity called Flick that contains attributes like flickTitle, flickReleaseDate, flickDirector, etc...

```
 var currentFlick: Flick?

 let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription! = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Flick", inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext)

 currentFlick = Flick(entity: entityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
```

Now you're free to write a fetch method that goes into your managedObjectContext and pulls that data out for you to play with it however you'd like. I know that's a lot but I hope at least some of it helps you get to where you want to be with this!

Comment: Beautiful, was able to fix it with this. Runs flawless now, thank you!!